# Crystal Report Error Missing Parameter when try to open in VS 2013 but working fine in VS 2008 and 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I convert VS 2005 project to VS 2013 ,everything work fine but Crystal Report give error "Missing Parameter" all reports work fine in VS 2005 but give the same error Missing Parameter in VS 2013

```
Here is my Code
  Dim crReportDocument As 
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
Private Sub OpenReport(ByVal rName As String)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page.GetType(), "popupOpener", 
     "var popup=window.open('" + rName.ToString + 
   "','','width=768,height=715,resizable=yes,menubar=0,
    scrollbars=yes,top=0,left= 
     0');popup.focus();", True)
    End Sub
Private Sub GetReport(ByVal DocumentNo As String, ByVal FromDocumentDate As 
  String, ByVal ToDocumentDate As String, ByVal ReportType As String)


    Dim sParameter(2) As String
    Dim sParameterValue(2) As String
    Dim NewDocumentNo() As String = DocumentNo.Split("|")
    Dim NewFromDocumentDate() As String = FromDocumentDate.Split("|")
    Dim NewToDocumentDate() As String = ToDocumentDate.Split("|")

    DocumentNo = ""
    FromDocumentDate = ""
    ToDocumentDate = ""

    For i = 0 To NewDocumentNo.Length
        If i <> NewDocumentNo.Length Then
            If NewDocumentNo.Length = 1 Then
                DocumentNo = "'" & NewDocumentNo(i) & "'"
                FromDocumentDate = "'" & NewFromDocumentDate(i) & "'"
                ToDocumentDate = "'" & NewToDocumentDate(i) & "'"
            Else
                DocumentNo = DocumentNo & "'" & NewDocumentNo(i) & "'" & ","
                FromDocumentDate = FromDocumentDate & "'" & NewFromDocumentDate(i) & "'" & ","
                ToDocumentDate = ToDocumentDate & "'" & NewToDocumentDate(i) & "'" & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If NewDocumentNo.Length > 1 Then
        DocumentNo = Left(DocumentNo, DocumentNo.LastIndexOf(","))
        FromDocumentDate = Left(FromDocumentDate, FromDocumentDate.LastIndexOf(","))
        ToDocumentDate = Left(ToDocumentDate, ToDocumentDate.LastIndexOf(","))
    End If
    sParameterValue(1) = " Where C.Transaction_No <> 0 And A.Document_No IN (" & DocumentNo & ")"




    Dim rName As String
    Dim _Report As New rptObject
    crReportDocument = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    Select Case ReportType
        Case "Cheque"
            rName = "rptCheque"
            crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"))
            With _Report
                .AddParameter("@WhereCond", sParameterValue(1), crReportDocument)
            End With
            'Case "ITXJournal"
            '    rName = "rptITXJournalVoucher"
            '    crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"))
            '    With _Report
            '        .AddParameter("User Name", Session("UserName"), crReportDocument)
            '        .AddParameter("@WhereCond", sParameterValue(1), crReportDocument)
            '    End With
            'Case "ITXCashPaymemt"
            '    rName = "rptITXTransactionDetail"
            '    crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"))
            '    With _Report
            '        .AddParameter("User Name", Session("UserName"), crReportDocument)
            '        .AddParameter("@WhereCond", sParameterValue(1), crReportDocument)
            '    End With
            'Case "Journal"
            '    rName = "rptJournalVoucher"
            '    crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"))
            '    With _Report
            '        .AddParameter("User Name", Session("UserName"), crReportDocument)
            '        .AddParameter("@WhereCond", sParameterValue(1), crReportDocument)
            '    End With
        Case Else
            rName = "rptGLTransactionDetail"
            ''  rName = "GLReport"
            crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + ".rpt"))
            With _Report
                .AddParameter("UserName", Session("UserName"), crReportDocument)
                .AddParameter("CompanyName", Session("CompanyName"), crReportDocument)
                .AddParameter("VoucherHeading", "Heading", crReportDocument)
                .AddParameter("@WhereCond", sParameterValue(1), crReportDocument)
            End With
    End Select

    crReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection("KT", "JVC", True)
    If cboReportFormat.SelectedValue.Equals("pdf") Then
        crReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + 
 ".pdf"))
        'Call 
  OpenReport(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + 
 rName + ".pdf"))
    Else
        crReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, 
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + rName + 
   ".xls"))
        'Call 
  OpenReport(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Reports/" + 
          rName + ".xls"))
    End If
    OpenReport("../Reports/" + rName + "." + cboReportFormat.SelectedValue)
End Sub
#End Region
```

Sometime report run but don't take parameter and show all record and sometime give error Missing Parameter

Comment: Are you using exactly the same version of Cristal Report in your new environment?

Comment: I used  Version=13.0.2000.0